# Solve a matricial equation, i.e a system of 16 equations with 16 unknown : Error when call solve function

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, solver, symbolic-math

I wonder under which conditions I could have equality between two 4x4 matrices. I build my two matrices from which I would like to get an equality.

But to get this equality, I have to solve an unknown matrix 4x4 whose terms are present in the two matrices 4x4.

To show you a practical example, I put below a small Matlab script that tries to follow all the reasoning explained above:

```
clear;
clc;

% Big_1 Fisher : 
FISH_Big_1_SYM = sym('sp_', [5,5], 'real');
% Force symmetry for Big_1
FISH_Big_1_SYM = tril(FISH_Big_1_SYM.') + triu(FISH_Big_1_SYM,1);

% Big_2 Fisher : 
FISH_Big_2_SYM = sym('sp_', [5,5], 'real');
% Force symmetry for Big_2
FISH_Big_2_SYM = tril(FISH_Big_2_SYM.') + triu(FISH_Big_2_SYM,1);

% Jacobian 1 
J_1_SYM = sym('j_', [5,5], 'real');
% Jacobian 2 
J_2_SYM = sym('j_', [5,5], 'real');

% Remove 4th row/column
J_2_SYM(4,:) = [];
J_2_SYM(:,4) = [];

%%%%%%%% Method 1 : projection before marginalisation %%%%%%%%%

% Projection
FISH_proj_1 = J_1_SYM'*FISH_Big_1_SYM*J_1_SYM;
% Check size : 5x5
size(FISH_proj_1)
% Invert Fisher_2
COV_Big_1_SYM = inv(FISH_Big_1_SYM);
% Marginalisation
COV_Big_1_SYM(4,:) = [];
COV_Big_1_SYM(:,4) = [];
FISH_Big_1_SYM = inv(COV_Big_1_SYM);


%%%%%%%% Method 2 : projection after marginalisation %%%%%%%%%
% Invert Fisher_2
COV_Big_2_SYM = inv(FISH_Big_2_SYM);
% Remove 4th row/column
COV_Big_2_SYM(4,:) = [];
COV_Big_2_SYM(:,4) = [];
% Re-inverse
FISH_Big_2_SYM_new = inv(COV_Big_2_SYM);
% Projection 2x2
FISH_proj_2 = J_2_SYM'*FISH_Big_2_SYM_new*J_2_SYM;
% Check size : 4x4
size(FISH_proj_2)


% Remove 4th row/column of Fisher matrix method 1
FISH_proj_1(4,:) = [];
FISH_proj_1(:,4) = [];

% Test equality between 2 matrices
isequal(FISH_proj_1,FISH_proj_2);

% Matricial equation to solve
eqn = FISH_proj_1 == FISH_proj_2;

% Solving : Jacobian 4x4 unknown
[solx, parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, J_2_SYM, 'ReturnConditions', true);
solx
```

Once I finished to build my 2 matrices `FISH_proj_1` and `FISH_proj_2`, I get the error in "solve" function :

```
Error using sym/solve (line 279)
Inconsistent output with 1 variables for input argument with 16 variables.

Error in demo_projection_dev (line 62)
[solx, parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, J_2_SYM, 'ReturnConditions', true);
```

The unknown is a Matrix 4x4 named `J_2_SYM`.

How to debug this error with solve function ? Is the syntax right if I put `J_2_SYM` unknown directly in `solve` function call ?

### Edit

Here a modified source where I tried to explicitly set a vector of symbolic variables (via symbolical vector `A`) but still an error remains:

```
clear;
clc;

% Big_1 Fisher : 
FISH_Big_1_SYM = sym('sp_', [5,5], 'real');
% Force symmetry for Big_1
FISH_Big_1_SYM = tril(FISH_Big_1_SYM.') + triu(FISH_Big_1_SYM,1);

% Big_2 Fisher : 
FISH_Big_2_SYM = sym('sp_', [5,5], 'real');
% Force symmetry for Big_2
FISH_Big_2_SYM = tril(FISH_Big_2_SYM.') + triu(FISH_Big_2_SYM,1);

% Jacobian 1 
J_1_SYM = sym('j_', [5,5], 'real');
% Jacobian 2 
J_2_SYM = sym('j_', [5,5], 'real');
% Flattness for vector unknown
A = sym('j_', [16], 'real');

% Set 0 to after 3
for i=1:5
  for j=1:5
    if (i == j)
      J_1_SYM(i,j) = 1;
      J_2_SYM(i,j) = 1;
    elseif (i >= 4 || j >= 4 && i <= 5 && j <= 5 )
      J_1_SYM(i,j) = 0;
      J_2_SYM(i,j) = 0;
    end
  end
end    
disp('here1');
J_1_SYM

% Remove 4th row/column
J_2_SYM(4,:) = [];
J_2_SYM(:,4) = [];

%%%%%%%% Method 1 : projection before marginalisation %%%%%%%%%

% Projection
FISH_proj_1 = J_1_SYM'*FISH_Big_1_SYM*J_1_SYM;
% Invert Fisher_2
COV_Big_1_SYM = inv(FISH_Big_1_SYM);
% Marginalisation
COV_Big_1_SYM(4,:) = [];
COV_Big_1_SYM(:,4) = [];
FISH_Big_1_SYM = inv(COV_Big_1_SYM);


%%%%%%%% Method 2 : projection after marginalisation %%%%%%%%%
% Invert Fisher_2
COV_Big_2_SYM = inv(FISH_Big_2_SYM);
% Remove 4th row/column
COV_Big_2_SYM(4,:) = [];
COV_Big_2_SYM(:,4) = [];
% Re-inverse
FISH_Big_2_SYM_new = inv(COV_Big_2_SYM);
% Projection 2x2
FISH_proj_2 = J_2_SYM'*FISH_Big_2_SYM_new*J_2_SYM;


% Remove 4th row/column of Fisher matrix method 1
FISH_proj_1(4,:) = [];
FISH_proj_1(:,4) = [];

% Test equality between 2 matrices
isequal(FISH_proj_1,FISH_proj_2)

% Check size : 4x4
size(FISH_proj_1)
% Check size : 4x4
size(FISH_proj_2)

% Matricial equation to solve
eqn = FISH_proj_1 == FISH_proj_2;


% Flatten matrix to 1D vetcor
A=reshape(J_2_SYM,1,[]);
A

% Solving : sigma_o unknown
solx = solve(eqn, A);
```

and the error :

```
A =

[ 1, j_2_1, j_3_1, 0, j_1_2, 1, j_3_2, 0, j_1_3, j_2_3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Error using sym.getEqnsVars>checkVariables (line 92)
Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.

Error in sym.getEqnsVars (line 56)
    checkVariables(vars);

Error in sym/solve>getEqns (line 429)
[eqns, vars] = sym.getEqnsVars(argv{:});

Error in sym/solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Error in demo_projection (line 88)
solx = solve(eqn, A);
```

What can I try next?

Comment: "I have posted initially on a wrong forum. That's why I transfer it here." - where did you post it? Please link from here to there, and here to there, so that the time of readers (in both places) is not deliberately wasted.

Comment: The error you are getting is because you have `solx`, but that is 1 variable and your system of equations has 16. You need to explicitly catch them, i.e. `[solx1,solx2,solx3....]`

Comment: @AnderBiguri . Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, the solution : 

`[solx1,solx2,solx3,solx4,solx5,solx6,solx7,solx8,solx9,solx10,solx11,solx12,solx13,solx14,solx15,solx16,
parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, [J_2_SYM], 'ReturnConditions', true);` 

generates the following error :

Comment: @AnderBiguri `Error using sym.getEqnsVars>checkVariables (line 92)
Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.

Error in sym.getEqnsVars (line 56)
    checkVariables(vars);

Error in sym/solve>getEqns (line 429)
[eqns, vars] = sym.getEqnsVars(argv{:});

Error in sym/solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Error in demo_projection_Jacobian (line 78)
[solx1,solx2,solx3,solx4,solx5,solx6,solx7,solx8,solx9,solx10,solx11,solx12,solx13,solx14,solx15,solx16,
parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, [J_2_SYM], 'ReturnConditions', true);`

Comment: Is the `Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.` ? Read the error message!

Comment: @AnderBiguri . The second argument of `solve` is a symbolic matrix. What to do to get back the elements of this symbolic matrix if there is s solution ? Regards

Comment: According to the documentation, the second argument is a vector of the variables you want it to solve. Read it here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

Comment: So what do you advise me to do ? I am lost for the moment. thanks

Comment: you may try to run the script.

Comment: It is unclear to me what type of equations you are trying to solve, and why you need to solve them symbolically instead of numerically.

Comment: @CrisLuengo . it is a matricial equation and I just want to get the structure of symbolic unknown `J_2_SYM`

Comment: f someone could try to make a synthesis in an answer of all what has been discussed here to find a solution, this would be fine to award him/her.